# Android 12 Incoming call notification popup and full screen intent like whats app and true caller

Tags: android, notifications

In android 12 and 13 foreground and broad cast receivers restrictions  are that's why am unable find solution for this. android 11 achieved this solution using  foreground and broad cast receivers. facing problem with android 12 and 13 .

Please help me on this

thanks in advance